# Unable to download .xlsx file from Python

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, postman, xlsx

I am trying to download an .xlsx file from Sharepoint. In Postman, I have been able to download this file no problem but when I try to automate it in Python I cannot seem to download in the correct format.

Here is my Postman request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{driveid}/items/{fileid}/content
Headers = { Authorization : Bearer {Token}}
```

It gives me a 200 response.
Then when I try the same in Python there always seems to be an issue.

```
url = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{driveid}/items/{fileid}/content
payload = {} #Not passing anything in since it's a GET request
headers = {
'Authorization' : f'Bearer {Token}'
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, data = payload)
print(response.text)
```

BTW I am recieving a 200 response code in Python as well.
The response just gives me a bunch of xml. I feel like what I am doing wrong is so simple. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer to this.
Only needed three lines of code.

```
output = open('name_of_file.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write = write(response.write)
output.close()
```

Hope this helps!